# Maven Jar file read external images

Tags: java, maven, jar, javafx

Hello I recently changed my JavaFX8 Project to Maven everything works well except loading files lying next to the JAR. This worked before but not any more.

Folder Structure:

Icons to load are located in /target/icons JAR file is located in /target

My code to read the files is as following:

```
    String applicationDir = (new File(".")).getAbsolutePath();
    String iconsDir =  applicationDir+"/target/icons/";
    File[] files = new File(iconsDir).listFiles();


    for (File file : files) {

        if (file.getName().endsWith(".png")) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

            Image img = new Image(file.getAbsolutePath());
            ICONLIBRARY.put(file.getName().split("\\.")[0].toUpperCase(), img);
        }

    }
```

It enters the loop and findes the files, but it crashes when new Image(file.getAbsolutePath()) get called with an 
Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found Exception.

I tried all kind of stuff with toExternalForm() and so on but nothing helped, i still get the exception no matter what I do.

I am really lost and maybe you can give me a hint what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Robi

Comment: Where have you located those icons in your source tree?

Comment: Hello this icons are located next to the jar file here is the full path
for example:
/Users/robi/git/projectxy/target/icons/icon_small.png
jar is at
/Users/robi/git/projectxy/target/jarfile.jar

But as I said the loop to find the files is working just to pass the filename to the image fails

Answer (score 1):

Hey Guys i got it running!

The solution was:

```
 Image  img = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
```

Thanks for all your help

What is weird, it makes a difference from in what directory I am running java -jar jarfile.jar it only works if I do that in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
URL resource = YourClass.class.getResource("FILENAME");
Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile();
```

This will find any resource as long as the resource is actually a file and not a JAR entry.

Comment: This will only work if the icons are packaged into the jar file which does not look like it.

Comment: Exactly, i want to keep them separat because the customer should be able to change the icons.